# Calling activity from fragment uses interface but Why?

Tags: java, android

Hello I am a beginner now, I wanted to invoke an activity from a fragment.
But i found out that the best way of doing so is by creating an interface inside the viewholder class.
I just wanted to know why it is done so.
A clear explanation of how does it work would be best..

Comment: Could you please add a code example of the call you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is what's known as a Callback Interface.

This is an interface that has the sole purpose of notifying other parts of your code that a specific event has occurred and allows you to respond to that event.

You should have seen these type of interfaces often in Android development, for example, `OnClickListener` is a callback interface for detecting when a View has been 'clicked'.

To continue with that example, when you use `view.setOnClickListener(listener)`, you're essentially passing a response to the View and telling it, "Hey, when you run your code and reach the part where you're 'clicked', run my code too."

So with that quick explanation, let's answer your question.

First, I want to point out that the best way to start an Activity from a Fragment is simply to call `startActivity()` inside the Fragment. There's no need to use an interface or anything.

The reason why you read that it's the best way to launch an Activity is because the Activity is being launched from inside a ViewHolder.

In Android, a lot of components were created with reuse in mind. An example of what I mean by this is the `RecyclerView`.

The `RecyclerView` is a component for displaying a scrollable list or grid of data. Notice how the `RecyclerView` wasn't designed for only a specific project, but it's actually a component that's flexible and strong enough to be used by any developer for almost any project.

How does it do this? By making itself functional, but with none of it's functions bound tightly to a specific project. For example, imagine what would happen if `RecyclerView` was created with a preset dark background and a specific view layout without providing a way to change the preset.

It's quite restricting right? That's why, it's very important that `RecyclerView` was created to be so flexible.

So back to the Callback Interfaces.

Like I said before, most of the components in Android development was developed with reuse in mind. Of course, certain preset values would be needed, but you'll make the parts that should be flexible be flexible.

So components like ViewHolders might be reused by other Adapters in your app. Components like Adapters might be reused by other RecyclerViews in your app. To make it reusable, you can't code anything too specific that would limit it's use to a specific class.

So I give you two scenarios:

1. You have a clickable View in your `ViewHolder` and you coded it to directly launch 'SecondActivity.class'. Now, whenever that view is clicked, it'll launch that `Activity`. This behavior won't change even if you reuse this `ViewHolder` in another Adapter that's **not** meant to launch SecondActivity.
2. You create a callback interface to use in your `ViewHolder`. When a View is clicked, you have it run the callback interface instead, so now, if the developer has custom code set... the custom code will be run too. In this scenario, you can set the ViewHolder to launch SecondActivity.class in one implementation, while another implementation might have it launch ThirdActivity.class, and another implementation might just launch a Toast saying the view was clicked.

Notice how the second implementation is much more flexible and you're now more open to reusing that component in other places?

So yes, while using a callback interface isn't considered the best method (in programming, there's never a best way, just a more efficient way to accomplish what you need), it's still a very great way to make your code more flexible.

One last thing... don't think there's no need to make your code more flexible if it's just your own code.

- Imagine if you had to make 10 of the same components with slight differences when 1 flexible one was enough...
- Imagine if you're updating your app in the future and need to change the User Interface. Components that are too restricted makes it very difficult to edit.

Answer (score 0):

## Creating a Loosely coupled Fragment

> Why we use interface for this?

One line Answer is **to create a loosely coupled Fragment.**

**More explanation:**
It might be tempting at first to call Activity method using `getActivity().someMethod()` . However, it is recommended to use an interface when you want to invoke Activity method from Fragment. Let's take a look.

You have an `ActivityA`

```
ActivityA{

     public void someMethod()
     {
          // do something
     }

}
```

And you have a `Fragment`

```
 class MyFragment{
    
    public void clickButton()
    {
        getActivity().someMethod();
    }

 }
```

Now in future, if You want to use this `Fragment` in some other `ActivityB`

```
ActivityB{

   public void someOtherMethod()
   {
        // do some other stuff
   }

}
```

**Now how would you use that Fragment?**

You will have to change some code in the fragment. It means the fragment is not loosely coupled with all the Activities.

Now let's take a look when we deal this thing with an interface

```
public interface MybuttonListener{

    public void myButtonClicked();

}
```

**What will be the Fragment code?**

```
class MyFragment{

  private MybuttonListener listener;

  public void clickButton()
  {
     listener.myButtonClicked();
  }

  public void onActivityCreated(Context context)
  {
     this.listener = (MybuttonListener)context;
  }
}
```

Now this Fragment is loosely coupled with all Activities.

You just have to implement the MybuttonListener in the activity and Override the method. That's it.

For `ActivityA`

```
ActivityA implements MybuttonListener{

   public void someMethod()
   {
      // do something
   }

   @Override
   public void myButtonClicked(){
      someMethod();
   }

}
```

**for ActivityB**

```
ActivityB implements MybuttonListener{

    public void someOtherMethod(){

        // do some other stuff

    }

    @Override
    public void myButtonClicked(){
        someMethod();
    }

}
```